# Why does API Gateway doesn't get the response from Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am a complete beginner to serverless computing and in general to AWS.

I have create an API using API Gateway service provided by AWS and integrated it with a Lambda function. This is the lambda function code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, {message: 'Hello this is a test message'})
};
```

Now when I test the API on AWS console, I am expecting the message that I sent from Lambda but instead I get this.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

Comment: What kind of Lambda integration have you set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deploy your lambda function clicking the Deploy button. It seems as it's loading the default one.